# Fill irregular shape with color android

Tags: android, colors, shapes, fill

I have one irregular shape png fully transparent image and **I want to fill color in it**. Please help me to do this. I can fill color in many regular shape but I don't know how to get exact points for irregular shape.
Image is as below :
[image: Fill Color]

Comment: I bet it is because you did not provide some example to start with....

Answer (score 0):

Define your shape through xml file and do it as a vector, example:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF333333"
    android:pathData="M19,6.41L17.59,5 12,10.59 6.41,5 5,6.41 10.59,12 5,17.59 6.41,19 12,13.41 17.59,19 19,17.59 13.41,12z"/>
```

This is an X icon. After you have this, you can set it to which ever color you want (tinting).

Comment: Let me check it out. By using this, will I able to apply gradient color ?

Comment: vector requires api level 21 and mine is 12.

Comment: You can set a tinting, thats for sure. Some gradient (rainbowlike), I can't guarantee.

Comment: Then you will have to make it as a .png file and use it as an asset. Don't forget to 9patch it.

Comment: Ohk, can you tell me how do i fill color inside that irregular shape ? whole image is transparent.

Comment: Try to find some library that does it, if it exists. If not, I'm afraid you will not be able to do such thing.